# A question about exogeneity assumption in linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, exogeneity

The exogeneity assumption is stated this way:

$E(e_i | x_{j1}, x_{j2}... x_{jK}) = 0$ for all i and j.

The first question is: is that "0" as scalar value or a vector?

The second question is:

Does this assumption also imply that this is true for any particular "column" of the design matrix, i.e.

$E(e_i | x_{jk}) =0$ for all i and j for any given $k \in {1, 2, ... K}$

Comment: The dimension of the $0$ is that of $e_i$. You should tell us what that is, you know what model you intended to ask about better than we do.

Comment: I think your answer answers the second part of my question as well. Since 0 has the same dimension as $e_i$, that means that $E(e_i | x_{j1}... )$ gives a pairwise conditional zero expectation.